# How can I select a div that have no id or an attribute with Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, html, css, jsoup

I need to select a div using Jsoup. I can select divs using their id or class by getElementById() for ID and getElementsByClass() for class attribute. However, the div i need to select is like below...

```
<div><h2 class='title'>Example</h2> 
.....
......
...... </div>
```

I must select this div. Div's unique property is just "Example" value in the < h2 > tag. So i must select the div according to < h2 > tag's text value. What should I do for this? please help Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following selector:

```
Elements e = doc.select("div:has(h2)");
```

This will select any div which contains a h2 tag. You can squeeze your selection set one step further by using the following:

```
Elements e = doc.select("div:has(h2:contains(Example))");
```

This will select all div which contains a h2 tag which also contains the text Example (case insensitive)

You can check out all the ways to combine selector syntax from http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax